# Alternative of REPLACE (which is provided in Microsoft SQL Server) in Postgres

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, upsert

I need something like

```
REPLACE into table (id, name, age) values(1, "A", 19)
```

in Postgres. The above query only works in Microsoft SQL Server. What I need is to get a **batch** insert query in PostgreSQL, and if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new batch rows are inserted.

i need to make something like following work-
CREATE TABLE conversation
(cid int primary key, conversationcreateat int,ClosedDate varchar);

```
with abc as( INSERT INTO conversation(cid, ClosedDate,conversationcreateat) values(1, 'a', 19),(1, 'b', 20)
```

ON CONFLICT (cid) DO UPDATE SET ClosedDate =  currentRow.ClosedDate, conversationcreateat =  currentRow.conversationcreateat
) select 1;

this is bulk upsert

Comment: Search for Insert into with on conflict clause or merge command in the latest version

Comment: It smells like `ON CONFILICT` or `MERGE`. To be sure, please provide sample data and the exact expected result.

Comment: "*which is provided in sql*" makes no  sense. SQL is a query language defined by the SQL standard and there is no REPLACE command in the SQL standard.

Comment: I agree with the others here. What you are looking for is a [`MERGE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html). I'm assuming that when you say "above query only works in sql" you are speaking of "mysql"? If you could share your table DDL someone may help craft the `merge` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Look if it works for you:

```
    INSERT INTO table1 (id , description , createdat, lastupdate ) 
    VALUES (1 , 'test' , now() , now() )
    ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET descricao =EXCLUDED.description, createdat=EXCLUDED.createdat , lastupdate= EXCLUDED.lastupdate 
--returning id , createdat;
```

this will garantee your insert gets done , the EXCLUDED. reuses the original insert values can be other value, the conflict columns tells to treat only the specified columns errors and can even return a value as it is commented.